# Optimization help querying XML from SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I have the following sql:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.tempuri.org/ef/audit/2.0' as a)  
SELECT AuditLogId, AuditDate, AuditUserId, AuditEntityActions, AuditXml

FROM dbo.AuditLog
WHERE

-- user type
(
    AuditXml.exist('/a:audit/a:entities/a:entity[a:type = "HOL.UserManagement.Data.User"]') = 1 and 
    AuditXml.exist('/a:audit/a:entities/a:entity[a:keys/a:key/a:name = "UserID"]') = 1 and 
    AuditXml.exist('/a:audit/a:entities/a:entity[a:keys/a:key/a:value = sql:variable("@userId")]') = 1
)

or

-- user role type
ISNULL(DATALENGTH(AuditXml.query('
    for $prop in /a:audit/a:entities/a:entity/a:properties/a:property
    where
    /a:audit/a:entities/a:entity[a:type = "HOL.UserManagement.Data.UserRole"] and 
    $prop[a:name = "UserId"] and 
    $prop[a:current = sql:variable("@userId")]

    return $prop')),5) <> 5
```

which will return any "User" or "UserRole" audit records from a database for a specified user. "User" records are easily identified as these are part of the key fileds, however the "UserRole" records are only found by a specific property (of which there are many):

```
...
<property>
  <name>UserId</name>
  <type>System.Int32</type>
  <current xsi:type="xsd:int">2571</current>
</property>
...
```

so it depends on finding the property name being UserId and the current value being the user id in question. Can I simplify this to use exist?

---

Using the answer below I was able to turn my sql into:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.tempuri.org/ef/audit/2.0' as a)
SELECT AuditLogId, AuditDate, AuditUserId, AuditEntityActions, AuditXml
FROM dbo.AuditLog
WHERE
-- user type
(
    AuditXml.exist('/a:audit/a:entities/a:entity[a:type = "Data.User"]') = 1 and
    AuditXml.exist('/a:audit/a:entities/a:entity[a:keys/a:key/a:name = "UserID" and a:keys/a:key/a:value = sql:variable("@UserID")]') = 1
)
-- user role type
or
(
    AuditXml.exist('/a:audit/a:entities/a:entity[a:type = "Data.UserRole"]') = 1 and
    AuditXml.exist('/a:audit/a:entities/a:entity/a:properties/a:property[a:name/text()="UserID" and a:current/text()=sql:variable("@UserID")]') = 1
)
```

Comment: Checking. Have you tried XML indexes?

Comment: @Evaldas Buinauskas I haven't. They look like they could help so I will look into using them as well as seeing if I can optimize the query. Thanks :)

Comment: Yep. If I remember right you'll have to add a primary XML index first and then there are three types of secondary indexes, one of them being property index. I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I'd avoid XML indexes... They seem to help in very rare cases only, while they can slow you down extremely. [Read this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/130969/70663).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an **XQuery predicate** combining both conditions:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'
<root xmlns:xsi="dummy">
<property>
  <name>UserId</name>
  <type>System.Int32</type>
  <current xsi:type="xsd:int">2571</current>
</property>
<property>
  <name>SomeOther</name>
  <type>System.Int32</type>
  <current xsi:type="xsd:int">2571</current>
</property>
<property>
  <name>UserId</name>
  <type>System.Int32</type>
  <current xsi:type="xsd:int">1111</current>
</property>
<property>
  <strangeContent/>
</property>
</root>';

DECLARE @UserId INT=2571;
SELECT @xml.query(N'/root/property[name/text()="UserId" and current/text()=sql:variable("@UserId")]');
```

Comment: great that helps a lot I played about with it a bit and changed the user role sql to be : or
 (
  AuditXml.exist('/a:audit/a:entities/a:entity[a:type = "HOL.UserManagement.Data.UserRole"]') = 1 and 
  AuditXml.exist('/a:audit/a:entities/a:entity/a:properties/a:property[a:name/text()="UserId" and a:current/text()=sql:variable("@UserId")]') = 1
 )